# Image scaling and loss of quality

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to shrink down an image to a smaller size for a while and cannot figure out why it loses quality even though I've come across tutorials saying it should not. First, I crop my image into a square and then use this code:

```
let newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
            let imageRef = image.CGImage

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
            CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, CGInterpolationQuality.High)
            let flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height)

            CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical)
            // Draw into the context; this scales the image
            CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef)

            let newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)! as CGImage
            let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: newImageRef)

            // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I've also tried this code with the same results:

```
        let newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 30,` height: 30)

        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

        UIBezierPath(

            roundedRect: rect,

            cornerRadius: 2

            ).addClip()

        image.drawInRect(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0)

        sharedInstance.my.append(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)
```

I still get a blurry image after resizing. I compare it to when I have an image view and set it to aspect fill/fit, and the image is much clearer and still smaller. That is the quality I'm trying to get and can't figure out what I'm missing. I put two pictures here, the first is the clearer image using an imageView and the second is a picture resized with my code. How can I manipulate an image to look clear like in the image View?

[image: Clear image view]

[image: blurry]

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.in/2015/12/how-to-resize-image-in-swift-in-ios.html) tutorial of how to resize images?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried this method..I can't figure out what the problem is, especially since I crop to a square first and then set it to 30x30

Comment: Why wouldnt you get a loss in quality?  You are shrinking an image. A loss is going to happen

Comment: Maybe the issue is you are getting a JPEG of an image,  that by default is going to cause quality loss.  your newImage is already a UIImage, so you dont need to go to JPeg and back to UIImage

Comment: are you using a table view cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the image view, click "Size" inspector and change the "X",
"Y", "Width" and "Height" attributes.

```
X = 14 
Y = 10 
Width = 60 
Height = 60
```

For the round radius you can implement this code:

```
cell.ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
cell.ImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

or 
go to the Identity inspector, click the Add button (+) in the lower left of
the user defined runtime attributes editor.
Double click on the Key Path field of the new attribute to edit the key path for the attribute to `layer.cornerRadius` 
 Set the type to `Number` and
the value to  `30`. To make a circular image from a square image, the
radius is set to half the width of the image view.

Duncan gave you a good explanation 30 by 30 is too small that's why the pixels or the quality of the image is loss, I recommend you to use 60 by 60

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
let newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 30 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, height: 30 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
```

This is because different iPhones have different size.

Comment: I think that's what passing `0` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample images you show, you're drawing the "after" image larger than the starting image. If you reduce an image from some larger size to 30 pixels by 30 pixels, you are throwing away a lot of information. If you then draw the 30x30 image at a larger size, it's going to look bad. 30 by 30 is a tiny image, without much detail.